# Cookie if statement does’t work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

### Goal

I am using the lightweight cookie plugin from [carhartl](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). What I am trying is to set a cookie, when the user is clicking on a close button of a notification bar. When the user close this message, it the bar should be hide, until the time is expires.

### The problem

Below is my script. So when the user clicked on the class `.notification-bar` the bar should be hide and set a cookie. If there is no cookie found, show the bar until the time is expired.

Unfortunately below code doesn’t work. I get no error message, but when I close the notification bar, and refresh the page, the message will appears again. The cookie is not been set after this.

```
var notifyBar = $('#notification-bar’)

                if($.cookie('demo_cookie') == null) {
                    notifyBar.css( "display", "block" );
                };

                $(".notification-close").click(function() {
                    notifyBar.css( "display", "none" );
                    $.cookie('demo_cookie', 'Demo Cookie', { expires: '<?php $expiry_date ?>', path: '/'}); 
                });
```

## [UPDATE]

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cddhez75/8/

The code for let the notification bar working, when there is a new post published on the WordPress site looks like this:

### the Functions.php file

Hook in the `transition_post_status` function of WordPress when there is a new post published.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    //Check if our post status then execute our code
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        if ( get_option( 'new_post_notification' ) !== false ) {
            // The option already exists, so we just update it.
            update_option( 'new_post_notification', $post );

        } else {
            add_option( 'new_post_notification', $post );

        }
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

### and the Header.php file

```
<?php 

// Get the new_post_notification which holds the newest post
$notification = get_option( 'new_post_notification' );

if( false != $notification ) {

    //Get the post's gmt date. This can be changed to post_date
    $post_date = strtotime( $notification->post_date_gmt );

    //Get the current gmt time
    $todays_date = current_time( 'timestamp', true );

    //Set the expiry time to two days after the posts is published
    $expiry_date = strtotime('+10 minute', $post_date);


    if( $expiry_date > $todays_date ) { 
        // Display your notification if two days has not been passed
        //echo 'New post published';


    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var notifyBar = $('#notification-bar');

                if($.cookie('demo_cookie') == null) {
                    notifyBar.css( "display", "block" );
                };

                $(".notification-close").click(function() {
                    notifyBar.css( "display", "none" );
                    $.cookie('demo_cookie', 'Demo Cookie', { expires: '<?php $expiry_date ?>', path: '/'}); 
                                        console.log('hello');

                });


            });

        </script>

        <div id="notification-bar-spacer">
            <div id="notification-bar" class="wpfront-fixed">
                <div class="notification-close">X</div>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="wpfront-message">
                                    Geachte leden, er zijn één of meerdere nieuwe berichten toegevoegd. <a href="http://wordpress.devrijheidbussum.nl/wordpress/login/">Ga naar login pagina ></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: No console messages at all?

Comment: What does `$expiry_date` look like? Is it before now? Are you including that goofy apostrophe in your source code? Also, a semi-colon after notifyBar wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I just set a `console.log()` inside the click function and it will send it to the console log. I have set it before and after the cookie.

Comment: Hmm. For the record, it's not clicking the `.notification-bar` that sets the cookie and makes the bar disappear, it's clicking on the `.notification-close` element, right? Can you jsfiddle it?

Comment: Above I have update the code with the PHP part for checking if there is a new post published in WordPress. @JonathanM I will create an JS fiddle in a minute.

Comment: Can you confirm that the cookie is really not set? (chrome://settings/cookies) - I can't see any code for "hiding" or not displaying the bar in case cookie is set, do I miss something?

Comment: @axel.michel, when I am checking my cookies, I can’t see the `demo_cookie` is been set. Also reset my browser history and cookies, and check it again that will result is no `demo_cookie`.
@JonathanM I have update my answer also with the JSFiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the errant close quote, you have a couple small issues:

1. You are missing is logic to hide the `notification-bar` when the cookie exists.
2. It seems like the `expires` value must be a number not a string.

Edit: snippets tool does not want to play nicely with the cookies, so see the [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cr9azLed/)

```js
$(function() {
    var notifyBar = $('#notification-bar');
    
    if($.cookie('demo_cookie') == null) {
        notifyBar.css( "display", "block" );
    } else {
        notifyBar.css( "display", "none" );
    }
    
    $(".notification-close").click(function() {
        notifyBar.css( "display", "none" );
        $.cookie('demo_cookie', 'Demo Cookie', { expires: 7, path: '/'}); 
    });
});
```

```css
#notification-bar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification-bar"></div>
<input type="button" class="notification-close" value="Close" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but then I have one question left. Inside the PHP I use the variable `$expiry_date` to set the time for how long the notification should be visible on the page after it is published on the site. So if you doesn’t close the notification bar, the notification will be displayed until the time is expired or if you click on the close button it will close earlier. How can I make the expire time in sync with PHP and JS? In the example on http://goo.gl/TQ6146 you can see that you can also use `Wordpress template tags` for the name, but I think also for the expires parameter..?

Comment: Just remove the quotes around `<?php $expiry_date ?>`

Comment: after change that, there is no error. Only it seems like, that after the expiry date the cookie is not removed.

Comment: What is the value of `$expiry_date`? When do you expect it to expire?

Comment: I have set the value of `$expiry_date` for 1 minute for testing.

Comment: The plugin you are using needs the expiration in _days_ so you will have to divide by 1440 to set the correct `expires` value.

Comment: Hi Dave, I was busy last week, but now the code will not close the notification bar and set a cookie. I used exactly the same code as you, I have copied all snippets, but it will give me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` on line 80 and that is this code: `notifyBar.css( "display", "block" );`. If I delete this one: `$.cookie('demo_cookie', 'Demo Cookie', { expires: <?php $expiry_date ?>, path: '/'});` the error will disappear, but it was working after I delete the quotes around `<?php $expiry_date ?>`. Do you know what it can be?

Comment: And do you know, when the user has closed the notification bar, how we can display the notification when there is a new post published before the expiry time expires? So if the expire time is 2 days and we post in day 1 something new, but have closed it yet...

Comment: How is that line rendering in your HTML? My guess is it has to do with what is in your `$expiry_date`